# Why does g give me error when used in this if condition?

Tags: python

I am trying to print prime numbers with this code:

```
import math    

b=[]
for num in range(2,1000):
    if num>1:
        if all(num%g!=0 for g in range(2,int(math.sqrt(num))+1)):
            print(g)
            b.append(num)
print(b)
```

My problem is when I try to print `g` why is it giving the error `NameError: name 'g' is not defined`. Why can't I print `g`?

Comment: Why `C#` tag for a python question?

Comment: The name `g` only exists in the generator expression.

Comment: Jeez, I don't seee any g!

Comment: I am unable to edit my comment, but see [this for an example of the generator expression scoping behaviour](http://www.librador.com/2014/07/10/Variable-scope-in-list-comprehension-vs-generator-expression/).

Comment: NameError: name 'g' is not defined

Comment: b=[]
for num in range(2,1000):
        if num>1:
            if all(num%g!=0 for g in range(2,int(math.sqrt(num))+1)):
                print(g)
                b.append(num)
hope it will help.above is exact code

Answer (score 0):

Because after

```
if all(num%g!=0 for g in range(2,int(math.sqrt(num))+1)):
```

executes, g has been removed from local frame.It is not defined as a local variable. You can rewrite the above code to a for loop and print g inside it, and it should be clear why you can not call print(g):

```
indicator = True;
for g in range(2,int(math.sqrt(num))+1):
    if num%g == 0:
        indicator = False
    #u can print g here
#outside of for loop, g is no longer in the local frame, it is now undefined
if indicator:
    b.append(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into when trying to `print(g)` are the scoping rules of generator expressions. There is a difference between Python 2 and Python 3 regarding scoping and lifetime of variables/names:

### Python 2

```
In [1]: list((a for a in range(5))); print a
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-eb5a741c3a99> in <module>()
----> 1 list((a for a in range(5))); print a

NameError: name 'a' is not defined

In [2]: list([b for b in range(5)]); print b
4
```

In Python 2, list comprehensions "leak" the names used inside the expressions to the enclosing scope, i.e. the names are accessible after evaluation of the expression, and will print the last value. In contrast to that generator expressions do not "leak" their names to the enclosing scope.

### Python 3

```
In [1]: list((a for a in range(5))); print(a)                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b1aaa69684c6> in <module>
----> 1 list((a for a in range(5))); print(a)

NameError: name 'a' is not defined

In [2]: list([b for b in range(5)]); print(b)                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-75ef5b1fd39f> in <module>
----> 1 list([b for b in range(5)]); print(b)

NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

In Python 3, both list comprehensions and generator expressions do not "leak" the names used in the expressions to the enclosing scope, i.e. the names are undefined after evaluation of the expression.

### Your case

So, regardless of which version of Python you use, you will not be able to access the variable `g`. If you want to see all values of `g`, you can use something like this:

```
import math

def printret(x):
    print(x)
    return x

b=[]
for num in range(2,1000):
    if num>1:
        if all(num%printret(g)!=0 for g in range(2,int(math.sqrt(num))+1)):
            b.append(num)
print(b)
```

On the other hand, you *know* that the last value of `g` will be be `int(math.sqrt(num))`, so you could just print that:

```
import math

b=[]
for num in range(2,1000):
    if num>1:
        if all(num%g!=0 for g in range(2,int(math.sqrt(num))+1)):
            print(int(math.sqrt(num)))
            b.append(num)
print(b)
```